# Flutter : Show Simple ProgressBar with Text and Freeze UI

Tags: flutter, user-interface, progress-bar, freeze

I want to show ProgressBar in my flutter app until web api return results and Freeze UI.

I'm new to flutter, Please guid me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

another approach is to use FutureBuilder:

```
Future<String> getData() async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () => "blablablablabla");
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
          } else {
            return Text("Contents: ${snapshot.data}");
          }
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```